# Insert new row with SQLite PCL

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, uwp

I am making a movieApp in UWP and i want to store a id from a movie if the user likes the movie. I have tried with txt but hade much problem with the access denied error. So i decided to use sqlite insteed.

I used this to get starded: 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Implement-SQLite-Local-8b13a307#content

I have been searching for a while now and all info i find dosent work with sqlite pcl.. it looks like many off the methods dosent exist that the examples i find uses.

So it seems there is little examples out there.. mabey you guys could push me in the right way..

This is my code so far for this:

```
private void LikeIt()
{
    var sqlpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Filmdb.sqlite");

    using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn =
        new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath))
    {
        if (File.Exists(sqlpath))
        {
            AdMovieID();
        }
        else
        {
            conn.CreateTable<MovieID>();
            AdMovieID();
        }


    }
}
private void AdMovieID()
{
    var sqlpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Filmdb.sqlite");

    SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath);

    //This is where i have tried some of the things i have found
    // like this: 
    //SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand insertSQL = 
    //new SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO MovieID(ID) VALUES(?), conn)<-- error: dosent work no constructor that takes arguments;
    //insertSQL.Parameters.Add(MovieID.ID);

    //Just to test if something is saved
   var allaId = conn.Find<MovieID>(sqlpath).ID;//<-- just tried this and it dosent work either "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    foreach (var id in allaId)
    {
        Test.Text = id.ToString();
    }
}
```

The class that i use with SQLite:

```
 public class MovieID
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not inserting a new item anywhere in your code, from what I can see.

Check out this simple code example:

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path)) 
{
    connection.CreateTable<MovieID>();
    connection.Insert(new MovieID { ID = "someId" });
    var movies = connection.Table<MovieID>().ToList();
}
```

If you inspect `movies` in the end it should have one item inside, a MovieId object with "someId" ID.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now!

I have tried many things some off them i have commentOut in the above code.. but like i said it never worked..

How did you know the specific command for this? Becuse i cant find any examples that show this for the Sqlite PCL..